# Make top section fill screen above the header in a onepage website

Tags: jquery, scroll, splash-screen, fill

I'm trying to make a onepage website with a splash page at the top that will scroll down to the header.

I want the top section to fill the whole screen with the header at the bottom hidden when the user first loads the page.  I will place a link on the splash page to scroll down to the header.

How can I do this?

My website is www.sleepn9.com/home.htm

My CSS for the top section is:

```
.sTop   {height: 100%;background: url('img/top_bg.jpg') center no-repeat;}
```

Comment: Just to be clear: Are you having problems with the top part not filling the screen as you intended or are you asking how you'd implement the scrolling when the link is clicked? Or both?

Comment: the top part not filling the screen

Comment: I already know how to add the link.  But I first need to fill the page of the top section with the navigation bar below hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using a percentage,you need to give the parent (probably the `html, body` in this case) a height so the section knows of which its 100%:  [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phk27k19/3/)

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the js fiddle?

Comment: Yes... I can;t figure out why.

Comment: I looked at your site, add `.wrap {width:100%, height: 100%;}` as well

Comment: Now how do I make the background picture fill the whole div?

Comment: Add `background-size: cover`, (or other back-ground size options)

Comment: I thought I knew how to do the link.  Any suggestions on a link to the header?

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with [some older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) (IE < 9 and sadly Safari on iOS < 8) not supporting it, I suggest using viewport units:

```
.sTop { height: 100vh; }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery to do something like:

```
$('.sTop').height($(window).height())
```

This works in Chrome on the console, however the menu doesn't scroll perfectly, so more work is needed.